# Is it possible to force redirection from PayPal to the website after successful payment?

Tags: 7, ubercart, payment-gateways

I'm using PayPal WPS with Ubertcart, and want to track the conversions using Adwords.

Is there any way to force *true* redirection back to the website within Ubercart?
The redirection in PayPal settings is already set to "On", however the users are still being asked to click to go back, or proceed to their PayPal settings page.

This results in losing the conversions.

Any ideas how to force the clients back directly to the website via Ubercart / custom module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is unfortunately no.

PayPal will always display this as an option to the client, so you can't force the redirection back after the payment has been completed.